# Como mostrar o número de visualizações de cada página do site com PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Em meu banco de dados na tabela `paginas` eu tenho os campos `pagina_1`, `pagina_2` e `pagina_3` representando as três páginas de meu site.

Nesses campos vou inserir as visualizações das páginas da forma abaixo.

No código de minha "página um", por exemplo:

```
<?php 
   $result = mysql_query( "SELECT pagina_1 FROM paginas" )
      or die ( mysql_error() ); 

   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
   $visualizacoes = $row['pagina_1'];
   $visualizacoes_mais = $visualizacoes + 1;
   $sql = mysql_query( "UPDATE paginas SET pagina_1 ='$visualizacoes_mais' " )
      or die ( mysql_error() );
   ...
?>
```

Com esse código consigo que, toda vez que uma página for acessada, as visualizações sejam incrementadas.

É uma forma correta de se fazer o registro de visualizações de cada página? Sei que é uma pergunta relativa, mas no fundo quero saber se existe outra forma ou se é assim mesmo: vou ter que criar um campo para cada página que meu site tiver, sejam 10, 100 ou 1000 páginas?

Comment: Quanto ao assoc e array, a diferença é que com `assoc` (_array_ associativa) voce usa `$row['nomedocampo']`, e com _array_ comum só pode usar o índice: `$row[2]`, por exemplo.

Comment: Cara, estava aqui editando para responder suas perguntas, mas seu questionamento já me fez perceber que de fato posso criar uma tabela exclusiva para isso independentemente dos usuários.  Em minha mente, a princípio, os usuários entravam no assunto por se tratar de uma página de acesso restrito, então eu somaria as visualizações de cada usuário para achar o número total.

Comment: Eu vacilei em dizer criar duzentos campos porque já estava usando o campo da página para segurar o número de cliques de uma input submit.

Comment: De qualquer forma, assim que visualizar melhor como pretende fazer, edite a questão com o máximo de detalhes relevantes, que facilita pra mim ou pra outro usuário a ajudar você.

Comment: Bacco, postei a pergunta da forma que estou fazendo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine o seguinte:

Você tem uma base de dados relacional, com tabelas. Tabelas nós relacionamos com linhas e colunas. Normalmente mais linhas do que colunas, na maior parte dos casos.

Geralmente o que varia nas tabelas é o número de linhas e não de colunas.

Que tal usar o mesmo sistema para o seu caso?

```
pagina          | visitas
-------------------------
pagina_1        | 127
pagina_2        | 17
pagina_3        | 32
home_page       | 56
pagina_4        | 4
```

Assim, para saber a contagem de visitas bastaria esta query:

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT visitas FROM paginas WHERE pagina='pagina_1'")
// só não usei binding aqui pelo exemplo ser literal.
```

E para atualizar o número de visitas:

```
$result = mysqli_query("UPDATE paginas SET visitas=visitas+1 WHERE pagina='pagina_1'")
```

Creio que vai poupar um bocado de dor-de-cabeça :)

O melhor é que você pode colocar isso num `require_once( )`, e mudar apenas uma variável.

```
$pagina = 'pagina_1';
require_once( 'contador.php' ); // em contador.php teriamos a parte do update.
```

Caso prefira, pode simplesmente colocar um `$pagina = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];` no `contador.php`, e usar o *URL* relativo da página como identificador.

Aí, em todas as páginas você teria apenas esta linha:

```
require_once( 'contador.php' );
```

E no `contador.php`:

```
$pagina = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

$minhaconexao = new mysqli( ... dados da conexao ... );
$stmt = $minhaconexao->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare('UPDATE paginas SET visitas=visitas+1 WHERE pagina=?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $pagina);
$stmt->execute();
```

O único cuidado neste caso é você pré-popular a tabela com várias linhas, e o caminho das páginas, desta forma:

```
pagina          | visitas
-------------------------
/               | 0
/sobre.php      | 0
/contatos.php   | 0
...
```

e assim por diante.

Comment: Podes crer. Melhor aplicação mesmo. Cara, eu não tenho preguiça de pesquisar nem de tentar fazer, mas na falta de conhecimento não há raciocínio que resolva. Comecei a estudar PHP há alguns meses depois de perceber que HTML e CSS é mais estruturação, portanto sei pouco e de MYSQL sei menos ainda, pois ainda nem estudei: venho usando superficialmente. Por isso entrei no fórum para obter ajuda de quem já faz isso a muito mais tempo. Vocês servem como reais professores. O que aprendo com suas respostas vou usar em outras situações. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Note que eu mostrei a idéia meio por cima, tem vários detalhes pra melhorar depois. Se esforce, mas quando "enroscar", pergunte :)